# How to disable the checkbox selection field from the columns menu panel

Tags: reactjs, mui-datatable, mui-x-data-grid

I am using MUI data grid. To show checkboxes for row selection, I have added checkboxSelection attribute to the data grid. Works very well.

```
<DataGridPro
                sortingOrder={['asc', 'desc']} 
                checkboxSelection
                disableColumnMenu
                disableSelectionOnClick
                columnBuffer={Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER}
                components={{
                   Toolbar: GridToolbar,
                 }}
                />
```

Is there any way to disable checkbox selection toggle?

[image]

I can disable other column toggles by adding hideable: false property. However, can't disable checkboxSelection as it's not a custom column.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to remove the toggle, overriding the style of the `Checkbox selection` item, to change its `display` property to `none`.

your CSS file would look like this:

```
.MuiDataGrid-columnsPanelRow:first-child {
  display: none;
}
```

[Check the sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-sea-3bgur6?file=/index.tsx).

This className was obtained by inspecting the element.

Comment: This will only hide the toggle. I want the feature to be disabled. https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-visibility/  this link has a demo of hiding, showing columns. We can hide all or show all columns. We can disable using CSS on the UI but cant disable functionality using CSS. I updated your sandbox, css solution doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. Its here -> https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/6720

Need to override default column.

```
{
        ...GRID_CHECKBOX_SELECTION_COL_DEF,
        hideable: false,
        headerName: 'Checkbox Selection'
      }
```